# How do you extract top level fields in multiple JSON Objects

Tags: json, scala, playframework

> given the JSON Value:

```
val json = Json.parse(
"""
  |[{
  |      "name" : "Agency Co",
  |      "worker" :{
  |        "FirstName" : "Bob",
  |        "age" : 44,
  |        "role" : null
  |      }
  |    },
  |    {
  |      "name" : "Agency Inc",
  |      "worker" :{
  |        "FirstName" : "Robby",
  |        "age" : 23,
  |        "role" : null
  |      }
  |    }]
""")
```

when you do:

```
(json \\ "FirstName").map(_.asOpt[String].getOrElse("Cannot find field")).toList
```

and a list of "FirstNames" will be returned:

```
List("Bob", "Robby")
```

However, nothing will be found with a ("\\") recursive lookup on the "name" field will not work even though there are two different occurrences of them. Using ("\") will only return the first occurrence I need a list of "names".

How do you return multiple top level "name" values in different objects?

Comment: `.validate[List[JsObject]].map(_.flatMap { obj => (obj \\ "FirstName).asOpt[String] })` or rather `validate[List[T]]` with `T` being a case class having the name properties (or a Value class).

Comment: @cchantep Thanks for leading in the right direction however I needed the "name " field not the FirstName field and using validate will only return a JsResult and will need a match case and only returns JsResult. The code you provided did not compile. I have resolved the problem I will submit answer in a post after this comment. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    val listOfObjects: List[JsObject] = json.asOpt[List[JsObject]] match {
      case Some(x) => x
      case _ => List.empty[JsObject]
    }
    listOfObjects.map(releaseObject => (releaseObject \ "name")
      .asOpt[String].getOrElse("Cannot find field"))
}
```

Comment: Rather use `validate`, accepting a `JsValue` which is not a `JsArray` of `JsObject` seems invalid

Comment: @cchantep `validate` doesn't work when you want to go to do other things with a `List[String]` as validate returns `JsResult[List[String]`. For example, if you want to transform the list and return it as a new value, you cannot with `validate`. Where as `asOpt` returns `Option[T]` and you use a `getOrElse` to get the actual value out of it.

Comment: I never said `validate[List[String]]`, using `Option` as a validation type is generally weird